# No progression after static-content:deploy en_GB

Tags: magento2, static-content

Running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` and `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` however in both cases it randomly stops and doesn't carry on any further, I'm unable to use ctrl C in my SSH to force it out as well.

Comment: Do you get any error message??

Comment: No error message, just hangs

Comment: try to delete var/view_preprocessed and pub/static folder, after that run the command `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

Comment: view_preprocessed seems to be the issue here. Once I delete it work fine

Comment: magento2 have so many issue my friend . :) Also i write the solution as answer for everyone..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete  var/view_preprocessed and pub/static folder accordingly. Then run

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

Hope this will help you